# How to integrate Eureka with Traefik

Tags: netflix-eureka, traefik

I don't understand how integrate Eureka with Traefik

I get an error in traefik.log :

> Failed to build configuration for Provider, error: strconv.ParseInt:
>   parsing "1522407483657": value out of range

### This is my traefik.toml

```
 defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
logLevel = "WARNING"

[traefikLog]
   filePath = "traefik.log"
[accessLog]
   filePath = "access.log"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":8090"

[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true

[eureka]
  endpoint = "http://localhost:8761/eureka"
  delay = "10s"
```

---

I dont' know if this configuration file is enough
but when I integrate Eureka with zuul, there are no issues.

If I use this traefik.toml file (without using Eureka), that's work.
What should I do ?

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http"]
logLevel = "WARNING"

[traefikLog]
  filePath = "traefik.log"
[accessLog]
 filePath = "access.log"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":8090"

[api]
  entryPoint = "traefik"
  dashboard = true


[file]
[frontends]
  [frontends.frontend1]
  backend = "backend1"
    [frontends.frontend1.routes.test_1]
     rule = "Host: localhost"

[backends]
  [backends.backend1]
    [backends.backend1.LoadBalancer]
      method = "drr"
    [backends.backend1.healthcheck]
    path = "/health"
    interval = "3s"
    [backends.backend1.servers.server1]
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8081"
    weight = 1
    [backends.backend1.servers.server2]
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8082"
    weight = 1
    [backends.backend1.servers.server3]
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:8083"
    weight = 1
```